# Custom nginx error page for "The SSL certificate error"

Tags: ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

If the customer will choose the expired certificate, the nginx server will show the built-in error page.

```
<html>
<head><title>400 The SSL certificate error</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<center>The SSL certificate error</center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I catch the error and show the client a different page?

Comment: Have you checked docs http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#errors ?

Comment: Thanks.
I processed the code 400, and in fact it was necessary to handle other error codes.

Answer (score 11):

**Please refer to http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#errors**

Define an error page for code 400 will not work. The working approach is

```
server {
    ...
    error_page 495 496 497 https://www.google.com;
    ...
}
```

So a user failed to submit a valid certificate will be redirect to google.com. This will work when `ssl_verify_client` is set to `on` or `optional`.

---

Another approach works only when `$ssl_verify_client` is set to `optional`, you could use `$ssl_client_verify` for redirecting.

```
if ($ssl_client_verify = NONE) { 
    return 303 https://www.google.com;
}
```

When `$ssl_verify_client` is set to `on`, it will not work.

Comment: Old ass answer, still relevant; helped significantly in 2023

Answer (score 5):

There is a way you can show the client a diffrent page. The way you do this is basically the same as stated above but instead you change the google website to a page that you created:

```
server {
    ...
    error_page 495 496 497 /error400.html;
    ...
}
```

Just be sure to include all you're custom pages in each server instance.